# Custom Rest API namespace and endpoints are responding with 404 & 503 errors

Tags: 404-error, rest-api, endpoints, namespace

I am new to WordPress plugin development. I was developing a plugin for WordPress that would be used to create mobile apps for WordPress Bloggers.

The whole source code of the plugin is at:-
https://github.com/delhideveloper/Delhi-Developer-PLugin-For-Blogger-Mobile-Apps

I have implemented the JWT Authentication in the plugin using firebase JWT. I know there was already a plugin for implementing JWT authentication but it was not improved since 2 years and I was facing some problems with it.

I have used only POST requests for every single API request just for simplicity. I hope it is not a crime to do so.

I have completely implemented the mobile app and the plugin. But there is a serious problem that I am now facing:-

The Rest API is the problem.

- Nearly 1/3 rd of the times it works perfectly and gives me perfect JSON response.
- Nearly 1/3 rd of the times it gives a 404 Error of this kind:-

```
{
    "code": "rest_no_route",
    "message": "No route was found matching the URL and request method",
    "data": {
        "status": 404
    }
}
```

- Nerly 1/3 rd of the time it gives me this 503 Error:-

```
    
        503 Service Unavailable
    
    
        Service Unavailable
        The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.
        Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I am struggling since a month and have not been able to figure out if it is a problem with server configuration, wordpress cofiguration, .htaccess, or my bad coding.

**Another important point to notice: ** The inbuilt WordPress endpoints are working flawlessly.

**Refreshing the permalinks is not helping.**

**Changing post requests to get requests did not help.**

**I have tried my plugin on multiple websites. I have the same problem everywhere.**

You can just try both the endpoints:-

Wordpress Inbuilt:

(GET) https ://delhideveloper.com/wordpress_blogger_app_demo/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

(GET) https ://delhideveloper.com/wordpress_blogger_app_demo/wp-json/wp/v2/post

My endpoints:-

https ://delhideveloper.com/wordpress_blogger_app_demo/wp-json/delhideveloper/v1/posts

https ://delhideveloper.com/wordpress_blogger_app_demo/wp-json/delhideveloper/v1/videos

https ://delhideveloper.com/wordpress_blogger_app_demo/wp-json/delhideveloper/v1/top_level_categories

Please add a comment if I should provide some more information about the problem.

My rest api code:-

```
/* Creating a new API End Point : User Registration */
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 
        'delhideveloper/v1', 
        '/posts', 
        array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'dd_retreive_posts_json',
        ) 
    );
} );
function dd_retreive_posts_json( $request ) {



    $posts_per_page = 10;
    $current_page = 1;

    $current_page   = $request->get_param("current_page");

    $posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
            'offset'=> ($current_page-1) * $posts_per_page ,
        )
    );

    if( ! $posts ) {
        $response = new stdClass();
        $response->code     = 'Failure';
        $response->message  = 'No Posts Could Be Retreived!';
        $response->posts    = array();
        return new WP_REST_Response( $response , 200 );
    }

    $posts_array = array();
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {

        $posts_object = new stdClass();
        $posts_object->id = $post->ID;
        $posts_object->title = $post->post_title;
        $posts_object->thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
        //$posts_object->url = 'https://prachyakarma.com/'. $post->post_name;
        //$posts_object->content = $post->post_content;
        //$posts_object->excerpt = mb_substr( $post->post_content , 0 , 100 , 'UTF-8' );
        //$posts_object->date = date( 'M j, Y' , strtotime($post->post_date) );

        array_push( $posts_array , $posts_object );

    }

    $response = new stdClass();
    $response->code     = 'Success';
    $response->message  = 'Posts Retreived';
    $response->posts    = $posts_array;
    return new WP_REST_Response( $response , 200 );


}
```

Comment: I've tried your code as it is (II've only changed POST to GET for easier testing) and it works here. Anyway, why are you creating a new endpoint for posts if the core already has one built-in?

Comment: Yes I am creating a new endpoin because I want to change the amount of data being sent. It will be difficult for me to change the API now as I have launched some mobile apps for it. The question I want to ask is that why should it not work the way I am trying to make it work. Is there something that I am missing in my code.